# Openlayers DragRotate map interaction not working

Tags: javascript, qt, openlayers, interaction

I'm facing an issue when trying to use the DragRotate interaction from OpenLayers. My map is embedded in a Qt Application by using a QWebView widget. As far as I know, the DragRotate interaction is added to the map by default as you can see in the documentation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nr3yv.png

Also, by default, the DragRotate interaction works by pressing Alt+Shift:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/McIn3.png

But when I load it and try to make the map rotate it doesn't work. The rest of interactions seem to work fine. I've also tried to add the interaction manually with `map.addInteraction(new ol.interaction.DragRotate());` with no success

Relevant information:

- Windows 10
- Qt 5.9.1. QWebEngine library
- OpenLayers 4.3.2

**Update**: Just tested it in Chrome browser and the map is able to rotate by pressing Shift+Alt and dragging with left click. But still no success in the Qt Application.

Comment: OK, so it seems that all the interactions that require some keyboard action are not working. I guess the reason is that pressing keys has its efect on the Qt Application directly and not in the map. I'm not sure if there is a solution for this...

Comment: I wonder if I will ever get an answer...

Comment: Similarly it is not working in Firefox (68.2.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a few years but I was searching for this as well, and figured it out.

```
import { altKeyOnly } from "ol/events/condition"

[...rest of your code here]

const dragDragRotateInteraction = new DragRotate({
  condition: altKeyOnly,
});
```